# Get data from multiple table in single query using Parse

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery, pfrelation

I am using Parse cloud as a backend in my app. Following are the tables in Parse,

- Users

```
objectId      name
    1         John
    2         Mick
    3         Nirav
```

- UserConnection

```
objectId  senderObjectId  receiverObjectId  connectionType
    1         3                  1            connected
    2         2                  1            deleted
    3         2                  3            accepted
```

(**e.g :** Here in UserConnection table at objectId 2, the connection between Mick and John is **deleted**)

Now my query is that, How to fetch user list along with the connectionType for the particular user ?

 For example if the user **Mick** fetches the user list from **Users** table, result should be,

```
name    connectionType
John      deleted
Nirav     accepted
```

How to retrieve data from both **Users** and **UserConnection** in a single query using Parse?

Answer (score 0):

For what programming language you are asking?
I can give you an example in Swift.

```
var innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
innerQuery.whereKey("senderObjectId", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser())

var query = PFQuery(className: "UserConnection")

query.includeKey("senderObjectId")
query.whereKey("user", matchesQuery:innerQuery);

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock...
```

Let me know if that works for you :)
I have also quite many issues about queries and parse...

Comment: In the ````whereKey```` do you mean ````objectId```` in place of ````user```` ?

Comment: in fact, it should be the `senderObjectId` as this is the pointer to your user you are asking for, right? I updated my answer.